# Javascript stops sending heartbeat when beforeunload dialog is active

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am working on a page where a user can lock records when he is working on them. While working on the records, a session (via RESTful API) locks records. Every 15 seconds, I am sending a "heartbeat" signal to my API to show that the session remains active.

I also have a "onBeforeUnload" function, which gives a warning when someone has made changes, but did not save them.

My problem is: While the beforeUnload dialog is up and running, it seems that te rest of my javascript code is not executing. This means that my heartbeat is not sending, and a background job will remove the session if the dialog is up for too long.

Is there any way to keep sending my heartbeat signal sending, while the beforeUnload  dialog is active?

Comment: Javascript is essentially single-threaded, if you leave aside webworkers. One option would be to send a different heartbeat before showing the dialog that would delay the session for longer, for example a minute.